# Help grasping trig integrals like $\int \cos^3(x)\sin^4(x) dx$

Tags: calculus

I have no issues with regular integrals, but when trig integral's like the one below pop up, I can't seem to grasp them. I've never taken a trig class before so maybe that is part of the reason. Would anyone be kind enough to explain the "easiest" way to deal with trig functions with powers in beginner laymen's terms? Is it possible to rewrite them in a form completely without the powers so I can solve with a u-sub or by parts? Any tips or tricks to dealing with integrals like these in an efficient manner? Thank you in advance.

Problem in question:

$\int \cos^3(x)\sin^4(x) dx$

Comment: Use $\cos^2x=1-\sin^2x$ and $u=\sin x$.

Comment: Whenever you have a product of sines and cosines, if one of them has an odd power, pull one out and use substitution. For instance, here, $\displaystyle\int \cos^3(x)\sin^4(x) \, \mathrm dx = \displaystyle\int \cos^2(x)\sin^4(x) \, \cos(x) \mathrm dx$. Now, by letting $u = \sin(x)$ and using $\cos^2(x)=1-\sin^2(x)$, you'll get $\displaystyle\int \left(1-u^2\right)u^4 \, \mathrm du$. [This](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/IntegralsWithTrig.aspx) might also be helpful.

Comment: @KM101 Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the trig identity $\sin^2x + \cos^2x = 1$,we get:

$$\int \cos^3(x) \sin^4(x) dx$$
$$= \int \cos(x) \sin^4(x) (1 - sin^2(x)) dx$$

Using substitution $u = \sin(x) \Rightarrow \frac{du}{dx} = \cos(x) \Rightarrow dx = \frac{du}{\cos(x)}$, the integral is eqivalent with:
$$\int u^4 (1 - u^2) du$$
$$= \int u^4 - u^6 du$$

Apply the power rule, we get:

$$\int u^4 - u^6 du = \frac{u^5}{5} - \frac{u^7}{7} + C$$

Undo substitution and get the final answer:

$$\int \cos^3(x) \sin^4(x) = \frac{\sin^5(x)}{5} - \frac{\sin^7(x)}{7} + C$$

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it. Thanks for spotting it